# Reorder column for small devices

Tags: css

I have this problem: web site page with few rows-2 columns on each row, I want to reorder position for small devices. 
Row 1: A and B
Row 2: C and D
Row 3: E and F
Row 4: G and H
to this order:
Row 1: A and B (no change)
Row 2: D and C (position switch)
Row 3: E and F (no change)
Row 4: H and G (position switch)

So I give my column *row 2 - D and row 4 -H* class name: my-content
and I use this css code:

```
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .my-content {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

But ... it`s not working. Please tell me how to fix this with css code and reorder columns, thank you in advance
P.S - I don`t understand nothing from Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Just change the floating of first column. For this HTML:

```
<div class="container switch-positions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            D
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            E
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            F
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            G
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            H
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .switch-positions > .row:nth-child(2n) > .col-xs-6:first-child {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Check it on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20817/), or run the snippet below:

```css
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .switch-positions > .row:nth-child(2n) > .col-xs-6:first-child {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container switch-positions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            D
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            E
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            F
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            G
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            H
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use the css code that you write: for class name I make switch-positions (I copy your idea). but its not working...

Comment: You haven't posted your html code inside your question, that is why you cannot get an accurate answer. As you can see, the code in my answer works fine, so you just need to adjust it to your case. If you post your rendered html source code, than I could help you further.

Comment: ty for the help, Ive make this without html, css or other code, ty for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for that: [codepen](http://codepen.io/vicodin/pen/RaXbrG)

*You can test it by shrinking browser device less than 800px width*

The key property here is `order`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
  .col
    flex-flow column nowrap
  .swap
    order 1
```

Comment: stupid question: do I have to give class name ( for the column)? If yes where to put in the code that you give me? Ty

Comment: @svet yes columns should have their classnames and stylings in css(in my example it's `.col {display: flex}` and `.col {flex-flow: column nowrap;}` for smaller screens.

If it's hard for you to read stylus and jade code in my pen - feel free to press _View Compiled_ buttons in the editor to see plain HTML/CSS

Comment: I`m new one and all this is really hard to understand... If I understand correct the code will be:@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
  .my-content
    flex-flow column nowrap
  .swap
    order 1

Comment: @svet Practice more and you will get the best results! Good luck :)

Comment: please tell me are this code is correct: :@media screen and (max-width: 800px) .my-content flex-flow column nowrap .swap order 1. In my case or I still miss something?

Comment: no, you've missed, you should use `order: 1` inside or your `.my-content` class and `flex-flow` inside of your container. I don't see full code so I can only predict that. If you're using Bootstrap 3, better use floats like in @skobalijic answer

Comment: I think it will be hard for you to change styles If you're not familiar with this languages, maybe you should contact specialist and give him access to your server

Comment: please can you help me with this? How to use your code? I have text and image, how to swap to be image and then text? I class name the image with : my-content, when in layout setting I use the code, but is not working. Help...